# Android Studio - Android Emulator presents the layout differently. There appears to be less height when the emulator runs the program

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have a program that runs fine and will load to the emulator but the screen length seems to shrink. I know the obvious mistake is not using constraint layout properly or not using the same emulator model/options but I believe I am. It appears to be effecting the entire application so I edited one of the buttons on the main menu to be really long to emphasize the problem.

Example and compare pics can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jELIV.jpg

I only noticed the problem when my feedback table got too long and started overlapping my 'calculate' button barely, then I noticed on the xml view I had plenty free space between the end of the feedback table and the calculate button. I guess it could be something to do with no action bar but I have moved objects to the very top and bottom of the screen and they appear fine so I am not sure.

XML file:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/sky"
tools:context="com.example.greg.securityeduc.PasswordMeter">


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/password_Meter"

    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="372dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"

    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"

    android:indeterminateOnly="false"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


</ProgressBar>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_EightChars"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="19sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="110sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_Number"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="19sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="160sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_SpecialChar"
    android:layout_width="45sp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="19sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="210sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_Uppercase"
    android:layout_width="45sp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="19sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="260sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_Lowercase"
    android:layout_width="45sp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="19sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="310sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_NoDates"
    android:layout_width="45sp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="19sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="360sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_NoRepeatChars"
    android:layout_width="45sp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="19sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="410sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_NoLoneNumber"
    android:layout_width="45sp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="19sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="460sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_NoLoneCapital"
    android:layout_width="45sp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="19sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="510sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_Top100"
    android:layout_width="45sp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="19sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="560sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_Number"
    android:layout_width="372sp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="160sp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/quicksandbold"
    android:paddingLeft="45sp"
    android:paddingTop="12sp"
    android:text="1 X NUMERIC CHARACTER(S)"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_SpecialChar"
    android:layout_width="372sp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="210sp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/quicksandbold"
    android:paddingLeft="45sp"
    android:paddingTop="12sp"
    android:text="1 X SPECIAL CHARACTER(S)"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_Uppercase"
    android:layout_width="372sp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="260sp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/quicksandbold"
    android:paddingLeft="45sp"
    android:paddingTop="12sp"
    android:text="1 X UPPERCASE LETTER(S)"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_Lowercase"
    android:layout_width="372sp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="310sp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/quicksandbold"
    android:paddingLeft="45sp"
    android:paddingTop="12sp"
    android:text="1 X LOWERCASE LETTER(S)"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_NoDates"
    android:layout_width="372sp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="360sp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/quicksandbold"
    android:paddingLeft="45sp"
    android:paddingTop="12sp"
    android:text="NO DATES (DD/MM/YYYY)"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_EightChars"
    android:layout_width="372sp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="110sp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/quicksandbold"
    android:paddingLeft="45sp"
    android:paddingTop="12sp"
    android:text="8+ TOTAL CHARACTERS"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_NoRepeatChars"
    android:layout_width="372sp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="410sp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/quicksandbold"
    android:paddingLeft="45sp"
    android:paddingTop="12sp"
    android:text="NO REPEAT CHARACTERS"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_NoLoneNumber"
    android:layout_width="372sp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="460sp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/quicksandbold"
    android:paddingLeft="45sp"
    android:paddingTop="12sp"
    android:text="NO LONE NUMBER AT END"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_NoLoneCapital"
    android:layout_width="372sp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="510sp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/quicksandbold"
    android:paddingLeft="45sp"
    android:paddingTop="12sp"
    android:text="NO LONE CAPITAL AT START"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_Top100"
    android:layout_width="372sp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="560sp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/quicksandbold"
    android:paddingLeft="45sp"
    android:paddingTop="12sp"
    android:text="NOT IN TOP 100 DATABASE"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_FeedbackBorder"
    android:layout_width="372dp"
    android:layout_height="500sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="110sp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittextborder"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.487"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/e_Txt_Password"
    android:layout_width="372sp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/password_Meter"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/password_Meter"
    android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="52dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittextborder"
    android:fontFamily="@font/quicksandbold"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
    android:maxLength="15"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="10sp"
    android:paddingBottom="4sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
    android:text="example"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="33sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.511"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_Calculate"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/e_Txt_Password"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/e_Txt_Password"
    android:background="@color/BlackShade"
    android:fontFamily="@font/quicksandbold"
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
    android:text="calculate"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.491"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_Clear"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/e_Txt_Password"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/e_Txt_Password"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dialog"
    android:fontFamily="@font/quicksandbold"
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.944"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_Feedback2"
    android:layout_width="350sp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/quicksandbold"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_Stg_Complete"
    android:layout_width="214dp"
    android:layout_height="153dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="700dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/quicksandbold"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_title_password"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="25sp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/quicksandbold"
    android:text="PASSWORD"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to create an [mcve] and [edit] your question. This is way to much code for a free help to dig through.

Comment: which type of layout group you have used(linearLayout /frameLayout / constraintlayout )?

Comment: Constraint layout.

Answer (score 0):

Your choose device for Preview tab is not as same as the Emulator. I think from my point of view that looks as same as in the blueprint. I also see that your're using the value-specified for the Width and Height attributes. That can also contribute to why the design and the emulator is not tally. Make sure you use `match_parent` or `wrap_content` and compare between both.

Comment: The bottom screenshot shows the emulator properties are the same as the preview tab. You can see right at the top of XML file I have match parent.